# Java projects without swing

Tags: java

I'm quite familiar with Java and I would like to work on a project on my free time but for some reason, I just hate having to work with Java GUIs. I'm wondering what kind of Java technologies are available out there that I can use for starting a non-GUI project.

Thank you.

Comment: It would probably help to know what you hate about Swing to provide useful answers.

Comment: Sorry, I should rephrase my question. I somehow mixed the terms swing and GUI.

Answer (score 7):

SWT is a popular GUI library (used in projects such as Eclipse IDE and other standalone projects) which uses native windowing components such as  Win32 on Windows and GTK+ on Linux. It achieves this through an abstraction layer with a standard library available for supported platforms. http://www.eclipse.org/swt/

For non-UI stuff (which the OP seems to be requesting now), there's [CHARVA](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html), which is a Java framework for presenting a "graphical" user interface, composed of elements such as windows, dialogs, menus, textfields and buttons, on a traditional character-cell ASCII terminal.

[image] [image]   [image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/images/vis-example.png))</sub>
[image]

CHARVA screenshots:

[image]
<sub>(source: [pitman.co.za](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/images/unitest-win.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[Java Qt Binding](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtjava/)

[SWT: The Standard Widget Toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)

> SWT is an open source widget toolkit
>   for Java designed to provide
>   efficient, portable access to the
>   user-interface facilities of the
>   operating systems on which it is
>   implemented.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is going to use a GUI you can use [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/) for the view and use pure Java for the logic

You can also use [FendGUI](http://www.fenggui.org/doku.php) which includes: buttons, sliders, trees, text areas, frames, tabs, etc.

Comment: +1 If you hate Swing for its complexity, use JavaFX. While you need to learn a new scripting language (more similar to JavaScript than Java), building GUIs with JavaFX is far easier and much more fun.

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy on the web, there's JSP.  You can use Flex and Blaze DS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) for a groovier experience (and if appropriate for your application).

Answer (score 1):

Java Curses: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/

> The Java Curses Library (JCurses) is
>   library for developing text terminal
>   based applications using Java
>   programming language. It is
>   implemented as a Windowing toolkit
>   similar to AWT, but built upon the
>   UNIX "curses" windowing system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try google web toolkit (GWT). And the ExtGWT lib is also an try worth.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with CLI (command-line interface) apps, especially if the project is just for your own use.  I like to prototype all my Java projects with CLI's first, because they're flexible and easy, and only once I've got things working do I consider adding a GUI.